# Matrix times vector vs vector times vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I can memorize this operation/logic easily. (3x3 * 3x1 = 3x1) And I understand it's a Matrix times vector.

[image]

But I can't operate a column vector * a column vector.

[image]

a * b =1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6

It's logic is different from Matrix. I thought vector is a matrix. I knew I misunderstand somewhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The dot product in matrix notation would be $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b}$, assuming $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are column vectors (i.e., matrices with a single column). If they are row vectors (matrices with a single row) then it would be $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^T$, with $^T$ denoting transposition.

So that could be one way for you to remember it. It's just the case that matrix notation is not always used for describing the dot product of two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

That's not matrix multiplication but the inner product of vectors in some [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space).

In general, you can only multiply two matrices when they have compatible sizes. In other words, you can only do multiplication to get $MN$ when the number of columns of $M$ is the same as that of rows of $N$.